# Error is not displaying on the HTML side in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

We are trying to set a limit on uploading image size. When it's larger than 2mb it showed error on console log:
**File exceeds the maximum size**
because on all functions where added `err => console.log(err)`
but when we replaced it with `err => err` and added this line in html:

```
<p *ngIf="err"> {{err}}</p>
```

It didn't display at all. Here is the full code:

```
OnFileSelected(event) {
    const file: File = event[0];

    this.ReadAsBase64(file)
      .then(result => {
        this.selectedFile = result;
      })
      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused-expression
      .catch (err => err);
      // Here was .catch(err => console.log(err)); before
  }

  Upload() {
    if (this.selectedFile) {
      this.usersService.AddImage(this.selectedFile).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.socket.emit('refresh', {});
          console.log(data);
        },
        err => err
        // Here was  err => console.log(err) before
      );
    }
  }

  ReadAsBase64(file): Promise<any> {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const fileValue = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
        const result = reader.result;
        if (!result) reject('Cannot read variable');
        if (result.length * 2  > 2**21) reject('File exceeds the maximum size'); // Note: 2*2**20 = 2**21 
        resolve(reader.result);
      });

      reader.addEventListener('error', event => {
        reject(event);
      });

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });

    return fileValue;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
 <p *ngIf="err"> {{err}}</p>
```

How to make it display this p tag with that error from the above functions err?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should create a global variable  in the class, since that one is local and not visible to HTML part.

```
 public error: string;

    ...

  OnFileSelected(event) {
    const file: File = event[0];

    this.ReadAsBase64(file)
      .then(result => {
        this.selectedFile = result;
      })

      .catch (err => this.error = err);

  }
```

And then:

```
 <p *ngIf="error"> {{error}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply your `err` object to a component object

```
public err: any;

Upload() {
    if (this.selectedFile) {
      this.usersService.AddImage(this.selectedFile).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.socket.emit('refresh', {});
          console.log(data);
        },
        err => this.err = err
        // Here was  err => console.log(err) before
      );
    }
  }
```

You can't bind your html to a variable in your callback inside your function, this `err` object is private to the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the error in a var:

```
public err: string;
```

And to replace your code using `this`

```
err => this.err = err;
```